# Is there a complete and portable list of all different integer types in C++?

Tags: c++, integer

I want to implement a function handling all simple C++ types (also STL containers and more types, but they don't give me headakes), with a generic function handling all other types, as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void dostuff(T& arg)
{ cout << "generic version" << endl; }
void dostuff(int& arg)
{ cout << "something useful" << endl; }
void dostuff(unsigned int& arg)
{ cout << "something slightly different" << endl; }
void dostuff(short& arg)
{ cout << "something slightly different again" << endl; }
// ...and so on for all integer types...
```

Here I restrict myself to integer types since they are causing all the trouble. Of course, the compiler complains if I implement the function for the same type twice. This happens when mixing things like `unsigned int` and `std::size_t`; it works on my system but does not compile on a 32 bit platform. I understand that problem, but I don't know how to achieve a portable solution.

I thought that the most systematic approach would be to use the std::int8_t (std::uint8_t, 16, 32, 64) family of types, since they won't overlap and are designed to cover the available range. It turns out that this is not enough, as demonstrated by the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "SIZE:" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(unsigned long)      = " << sizeof(unsigned long) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(unsigned long long) = " << sizeof(unsigned long long) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(std::size_t)        = " << sizeof(std::size_t) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(std::uint64_t)      = " << sizeof(std::uint64_t) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "SIGNED?" << std::boolalpha << endl;
    cout << std::is_signed<unsigned long>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_signed<unsigned long long>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_signed<std::size_t>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_signed<std::uint64_t>::value << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "SAME?" << endl;
    cout << std::is_same<unsigned long, unsigned long long>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_same<unsigned long, std::size_t>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_same<unsigned long, std::uint64_t>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_same<unsigned long long, std::size_t>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_same<unsigned long long, std::uint64_t>::value << endl;
    cout << std::is_same<std::size_t, std::uint64_t>::value << endl;
}
```

On my 64bit MacOS system with clang 3.8 it gives the following output:

```
SIZE:
sizeof(unsigned long)      = 8
sizeof(unsigned long long) = 8
sizeof(std::size_t)        = 8
sizeof(std::uint64_t)      = 8

SIGNED?
false
false
false
false

SAME?
false
true
false
false
true
false
```

So I have four 64bit unsigned integer types, but they are actually referring to only two *different* types. There are more candidates, like `std::uintptr_t`, `std::ptrdiff_t`, and `std::uint_fast64_t`, and I don't even know if that list is complete.
The definition of which types are the same looks arbitrary to me, although I see that for the exact problem I am facing we want `long` and `long long` to be treated as different.

**Question:** Is there any way to implement the above function for an exhaustive list of different integer types so that I don't run into trouble on a different platform? If so, what's this list? If no, what's the best way to achieve the desired behavior (handling of all integer types, meaningful default behavior for unknown types, portable solution)?

Comment: I'd advise using only `std::intN_t` and `std::uintN_t` (where N = 8,16,32,64) if one starts to care about portability and sizes.

Comment: Use types from `<cstdint>` header.

Comment: @lisyarus That's what I did, and it turns out that it did not cover all integer types, like std::size_t in my example.

Comment: @tglas Sorry, didn't read the question carefully. Also, I missed `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t`. Nevertheless, all this looks like an XY problem. Why do you actually need such specializations? Is knowing signedness and size too little information for you?

Comment: @lisyarus I use `unsigned int` and `std::size_t` in different places where appropriate in my programs, and I want the ability to pass any variable to my function without having to think about explicit casts. Knowing signedness and size is exactly what I need inside the function, but how do I end up with one function for each signedness/size combination so that all integer types are forwarded to the correct function? I don't want platform-dependent holes so some random types are forwarded to the generic version, depending on system and compiler.

Comment: A minute ago there was an answer linking to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types. It was deleted when I was just about to upvote. Looked very promising, and at the very least useful to me... hope it comes back :)

Comment: @tglas "Knowing signedness and size is exactly what I need inside the function" then why not just write, say, 8 implementations for all combinations of sign and size and make the function to statically dispatch between these implementations?

Comment: @tglas I can show how to achieve this if my last comment's suggestion would suit you.

Comment: @lisyarus I am not sure what you mean with "to statically dispatch ...". Please elaborate, maybe in an anser. How to do that? One could think that writing 8 versions for the intN_t and uintN_t types does the trick (that's what I tried), but then std::size_t does not compare equal to any of these on my system (std::is_same), see the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specializing for all integral types is generally a very bad idea. Based on the discussion in the comments, I assume that static dispatch on the size & signedness of types would suit you. Here's how it can be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, unsigned Size, bool Signed>
struct foo_impl;

template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T, 1, false>
{
    static void foo (T & x) { std::cout << x << " is unsigned 8-bit" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T, 1, true>
{
    static void foo (T & x) { std::cout << x << " is signed 8-bit" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo_impl<T, 2, false>
{
    static void foo (T & x) { std::cout << x << " is unsigned 16-bit" << std::endl; }
};

// more specializations ...

template <typename T>
void foo (T & x)
{
    // dispatch based on size & signedness
    foo_impl<T, sizeof(T), std::is_signed<T>::value>::foo(x);
}

int main ( )
{
    char a = 5;
    std::uint8_t b = 6;
    unsigned short c = 7;

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
}
```

[Live on ideone](http://ideone.com/RsGQTm)

Comment: I incorporated this into my actual application and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @tglas Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to do something different for each specific integral type, even if you could enumerate all the types in your program you couldn't make up the specific special logic.

Instead what I'm going to suggest is implement the special logic for say `short`, `int`, `unsigned`, etc as you need, and put a static assert that `is_integral<T>` is `false` in your main template, with a message that it's being called with an unsupported integral type that needs to have custom logic determined and written.

Comment: But that's hardly portable. If I implement things for `unsigned int` then I can pass a `std::size_t` on a 32bit platform, the same code fails to compile on a 64bit platform. Adding the `std::size_t` overload breaks the code on a 32bit system. I need a way out of that dilemma.